# Kendoui Combobox has second on change triggered

Tags: jquery, data-binding, combobox, kendo-ui

I have three combo boxes (department, category and sub category), see attached jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cFLQr/1/

When I select the second combobox (category) the change event is fired but, for some reason, if I then click then third combobox immediately (without any other interaction on the page) I get an error of "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

If however I do things slightly differently and select the second combobox (category) then make a click elsewhere on the page, the event is fired twice (once on change and once on click elsewhere on page). The second change event stops the above error and passes the correct information.

Please can you help me to understand why there is a second change event on clicking elsewhere on the page and also why the first change event doesn't do the job of the second change event. :-/

Thank you very much
Rich

PS Worth mentioning I've chucked some dummy data into these for fiddle. I call data dynamically in my local environment

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is that you are using **selectedIndex** field exposed by the client object - which is actually not a public field. It is for internal usage.

If you want to get the value and/or the text when the change event occurs you need to use the corresponding method - [**text()** and **value()**](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#text).

In the **change** event handler **this** points to the client object.

so you can type `this.text()` to get the text and `this.value()` to get the value :)

Here is an updated jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cFLQr/4/